# Shopping List - multiple stores optimization

Tags: shopping-cart, shopping

Like most people, I can visit a variety of stores to get my shopping done, many of which have overlapping inventory.  Currently I have one shopping list for the grocery store, one for the drugstore (e.g. CVS, Walgreens), one for the hardware store (e.g. Home Depot, Lowes) and one for Costco (I live in the U.S., btw).

So if I need a hammer, that'll go under Hardware Store.  And if I need a bag of chips, that'll go under Grocery Store.  Turns out, some CVS's are extensive and sell both hammers and bags of chips.  If only my shopping list had informed that I could go CVS instead of one trip to a grocery store and another to a hardware store.

I'm looking for an app that lets me:

1. Create a list of stores that I shop at
2. Add items to my shopping list.  For each item, indicate where that item can be found (e.g. **hammer - {CVS, Home Depot}**).
3. Generate a list, for each store, of items I can get there.
4. A great (but not required) feature would be to optimize my shopping, listing the smallest set of stores to cover all my items.

I'd pay a few bucks for it. Let's say < $30/year. I want it to be available on PC and android phone. So don't care if it's a mobile-friendly web app or a native app + web app for my PC.

Does such a tool exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it's not specifically designed for this, [TickTick](https://ticktick.com) will do what you want. Simply use tags to specify which stores an item is available at.

It does not have any functionality to meet your optional feature (optimizing your shopping).

It is cross-platform, and works on Windows, Android, iOS, and macOS.  It also has a good web-app (which is currently the only support for Linux), and browser extensions for Firefox and Chrome.

For the most part, it is well designed, although multiple clicks are required to access tags in the web interface.

It is free to use, up to certain limits.  The differences between the free and paid versions are [listed here](https://support.ticktick.com/hc/articles/360010640652-What-are-the-differences-between-TickTick-Free-and-TickTick-Premium-).  The paid version is currently $2.79/mo, or $27.99/yr if paying in advance (see [here](https://ticktick.com/about/upgrade)).

One downside is that sometimes their support team does not answer questions or bug reports posted on their [help forums](https://help.ticktick.com/forum) in a timely fashion.  There is still an unresolved bug that shows up when using Firefox (but it's just aesthetic) that was reported many months ago.

TickTick claims your data is [stored on Amazon AWS servers](https://ticktick.com/about/security).  TickTick also claims that all data is encrypted with AES-256.  The source code is closed-source, so there is no way to verify these claims.  Since your password is stored in their database, and the format (such as whether or not it is hashed) is not disclosed, one must assume that, technically, they can access your data.  From their [help](https://support.ticktick.com/hc/articles/360035545551-Privacy-and-Security-):

> Your information is only used internally, and the access to personal data is restricted to a very small number of employees at TickTick who need access for specific reasons to improve the application.

The employees that can potentially access your personal data are unknown, and is discussed [here](https://help.ticktick.com/forum/topic/381147/security---privacy-of-ticktick) and [here](https://help.ticktick.com/forum/topic/380895/team--company-behind-ticktick).